Why are interceptors not working in Angular v17?
I'm trying to learn Angular and I'm using version 17. I've reached the topic of interceptors, but no matter what I do, I can't get the interceptor to work. The token doesn't appear in the header response section. Here is the code
LoginComponent.ts
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, ReactiveFormsModule, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrl: './login.component.scss'
})
export class LoginComponent {

  loginForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private http: HttpClient) {
    this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]]
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    if (this.loginForm.valid) {
      localStorage.setItem("token", "test1234")
      this.http.post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', this.loginForm.value)
        .subscribe(
          response => {
            console.log('Login successful', response);
          },
          error => {
            console.error('Login error', error);
          }
        );
    } else {
      console.log('Form is invalid');
    }
  }
}

app.config.ts

import { ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { provideHttpClient, withInterceptors } from '@angular/common/http';
import { demoInterceptor } from './demo.interceptor';
import { provideClientHydration } from '@angular/platform-browser';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideClientHydration(),
    provideHttpClient(withInterceptors([demoInterceptor])),
  ],
};

demo.interceptors.ts
import { HttpInterceptorFn } from '@angular/common/http';

export const demoInterceptor: HttpInterceptorFn = (req, next) => {
  const authToken = localStorage.getItem("token");

  // Clone the request and add the authorization header
  const authReq = req.clone({
    setHeaders: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${authToken}`
    }
  });

  // Pass the cloned request with the updated header to the next handler
  return next(authReq);
};

I tried all the solutions provided to similar issues on Stack Overflow, but none of them worked.

Remove the HttpClientModule import.
You're overriding the interceptors on your component with this.

Thank you very much. I'm stuck here and have been dealing with this since yesterday. you saved me from a big trouble
